# How to remove multiple empty array wrappers and just keep object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

How to remove all the empty array wrappers ?

From this to

```
[[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]]
```

To this

```
{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}
```

If the the object as an array it should be maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `recursion`-

```js
const input = [[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]];

function flattenDeep(input) {
    return input.reduce((accu, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? accu.concat(flattenDeep(val)):accu.concat(val), []);
}

console.log(flattenDeep(input));
```

You can also use inbuilt function `flat` if you know the deepness of nesting.

```js
const input = [[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]];

console.log(input.flat(2));
```

Comment: But the final output is still in array.

Comment: @user007 - If you want to be in an object. You can spread the array contents within an object like - `console.log({...flattenDeep(input)});`